# What if a Dog attacks an intruder?

Tags: criminal-law, assault, animals

If your pet dog were to attack an intruder during a violent home invasion and seriously injured him, does the dog need to be put down?

Comment: Which state, or country does this question apply to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no (it does vary state by state in the US). The intruder took a risk when breaking in and therefore knew that there might be a threat to his life. A judge would generally side with you if the intruder broke into your house, and got attacked by the dog in the house he broke into.

http://blogs.lawyers.com/attorney/dog-bites/can-a-burglar-sue-me-if-my-dog-attacks-them-29325/
http://doglaw.hugpug.com/doglaw_082.html

Comment: But that's not the question asked. If you have a seriously dangerous dog, and his victim is a burglar, that may be tough luck for the burglar. But the police would still find out that you have a vicious dog that might kill your neighbour's young children, and do something about it.

Comment: @gnasher729 In practice, a dog attacking a burglar is almost never going to be considered evidence that you have a vicious dog.